# OpenGL glm::translate doesn't translate matrix as was hoped

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, transformation, glm-math

I need to scale a cube in 50 times and move it along the Z-axis on `3.0f` units:

```
glm::mat4 model(1.0f);
model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(50.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f));
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f));
```

But as the result I got this:
[image]

I was expecting that the block will be almost in the centre, but it isn't. What am I doing wrong?
My vertex shader:

```
const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"

"uniform mat4 model;\n"
"uniform mat4 view;\n"
"uniform mat4 projection;\n"

"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0f);\n"
"}\n\0";
```

My View and Projection matrices:

```
glm::vec3 cameraPos = glm::vec3(-300.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glm::vec3 cameraFront = glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glm::vec3 cameraUp = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glm::mat4 projection = glm::infinitePerspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.001f);
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(cameraPos, cameraPos + cameraFront, cameraUp);
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
```

My arrays:

```
float vertices[] = {
        0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f,
    };
    unsigned int indices[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0,
        1, 0, 4,
        1, 4, 5,
        3, 7, 4,
        3, 4, 0,
        6, 2, 1,
        6, 1, 5,
        6, 7, 3,
        6, 3, 2,
        5, 4, 7,
        5, 7, 6,
    };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the glm API documentation for [`translate()`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00668.html#ga1a4ecc4ad82652b8fb14dcb087879284):

> Builds a translation 4 * 4 matrix created from a vector of 3 components.
>
> Parameters
>
> `m` Input matrix multiplied by this translation matrix
> `v` Coordinates of a translation vector.

This means that the model matrix can be expressed as:

```
model = scale * translate
```

This causes that the translation is multiplied by the scale. Note, the multiplication has to be "read" from the left to the right. (See [GLSL Programming/Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations))

Swap the scale and the translation to solve your issue:

```
glm::mat4 model(1.0f);
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f));
model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(50.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f));
```